# Recursive java method, get mother, grand mother, great grand mother and so on

Tags: java, recursion

I have a list Dogs in a text file with the following format:
id:fatherid:motherid:born:owner:breed
ex:
3:2:1:2000:Scotty:Peter:dachs

I then populate an array list with objects of dog. I Need a method that returns all the mothers for a dog with a given id. I already have methods for: getMother, getDog, getChildren, getParents, existDog. getDog and getMother returns a Dog, getChildren and getParents returns a String.  Now i need a method that gives me the mother, grand mother, great grand mother and so on. I do not know how to make this method. This code gives me the mother and grand mother of a dog:

```
public String getMotherTree(int id) {
    String output = "";
    if (existDog(id)) {
        Dog mother = GetMother(id);
        output += mother.toString();
        int morId = mother.getId();
        Dog grandMother= GetMother(motherId);
        output += grandMother.toString;
        return output;

    }
    output = "The dog with that id do not exist!";
    return output;
}
```

I think that what i need is a recursive method, but i do not know how to do this.

Comment: Dog-Mother is a 1:1 relationship, so this could also be done in a `for` or `while` loop. Recursive method is not necessary.

Comment: Ok, can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'd create a method that calls itself with another parameter unless some condition is met.

In your case, you might use `getMotherTree()` (or some adjusted method):

```
public String getMotherTree(int id) {
  String output = "";
  if (existDog(id)) {
    Dog mother = GetMother(id);
    output += mother.toString();
    int morId = mother.getId();
    return output + ", " + getMotherTree(morId); //recursion
  }

  //return an empty string if the dog doesn't exist
  //this basically ends the recursion
  return output;
}
```

As BalusC pointed out recursion is not necessary here, so please view that as a learning exercise only.

Comment: This example is not correct. You should not return the result of the recursive call. This way you end up with the uppermost mother in the output only, while the OP needs them all chained. You should add it to the `output`.

Comment: @BalusC oops, deleted too much ;), I'll fix that.

Comment: @Twistar yes, you'd need to check if `mother` is null as well. I'll leave that as an excercise for you :)

Comment: I got rid of the NullPointer as well :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion for this: you could replace your IF with a WHILE, and after adding the mother to the String, replace id with the id of the mother.  (If you still want a message if the dog doesn't exist, just check if output is blank or not before returning.)

Note that you have a logic problem (which what I just described doesn't solve): just because a dog exists doesn't mean it has a mother (or your loop/recursion would never end!), so calls to any method of this missing mother should fail.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done recursively (which is computationally expensive but perhaps simpler code to understand) or can be done iteratively. Here's an iterative solution:

```
public String getMotherTree(int id) {
    if (!existDog(id)) {
        return "The dog with that id do not exist!";
    }
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (Dog mother = GetMother(id); mother != null; mother = mother.getMother()) {
        if (output.length() > 0) {
            output.append(", ");
        }
        output.append(mother.toString());
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

This assumes that `aDog.getMother()` returns `null` if `aDog` has no mother in the data base.